# What are the advantages and disadvantages to using a griddle instead of a cast-iron skillet?

Tags: equipment, skillet, griddle

I have moved into a house with a nice Wolf-range griddle, and I would like to know what the primary advantages of the griddle are over a cast-iron skillet, including, is there anything I can do with a griddle that can not be done with a skillet?

I have found that the primary downside to using the griddle is the time it takes to heat up, so when cooking for one, I would choose the skillet. The primary advantage of the griddle is that it provides a larger, easier cooking space.

Am I missing other major advantages of having a griddle?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you don't have the edge of a pan in the way when going to flip things, but it also means that you don't have a mass of metal there to add as a heat sink, which can help dramatically when pre-heating your pans, as they'll be evenly heated across their bottom more quickly (at least, compared to something of the same material, such as a cast iron skillet)

More importantly, in my opinion, is that without the sides, you don't hold in moist air, so when cooking things like hash browns, you can get a better crust on 'em without steaming them.

Answer (score 3):

I would say the biggest advantage, which you've hinted at, is being able to use a spatula for quick and easy flipping (think pancakes, french toast, etc). Apart from its shape and size, there really is no other difference (even the difference in heat-up time, I've found, is negligible).

Answer (score 2):

Surface area is the biggest difference. You can do a much larger job on a griddle than in a skillet. Even 2 or 3 jobs at time, and when you are done there is just the griddle to clean and not several items.

You will also want to pick up a '[bacon press](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00004UE7B)' to minimize splatter when you put bacon on your griddle.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to just use to frying pans ('skillets'). The lack of sides allows stuff to fall off too easily - I fried chopped onions today - and there's no carrying handle - so you can't move the griddle to plate up. The other downer - my griddle's cast iron and it's just cracked while heating it !